# How to get the "github" CLI to open the new GitHub Desktop beta?

Tags: github, github-desktop

Since updating GitHub Desktop to the new beta version, my `github` CLI command has gone. How do I get it back? Is there some kind of alias I can add to my shell config?

(The CLI simply opened the CWD with GitHub Desktop.)

Answer (score 0):

From the top menu, select Repository > Open command prompt. This will open the Command Prompt (cmd) with the project directory in view. Earlier versions of GitHub Desktop opened the PowerShell, whereas this (Version 0.62) opens the Command Prompt.